# Meteor Authenticate email/password from a different server with bcrypt

Tags: ruby, authentication, meteor, devise, meteor-accounts

I want to let my `meteor` users login through a `ruby` app.

Where I am

- I have two websites, both on the same domain, both share the same MongoDB.
- One is a METEOR-app with `accounts-password` (which uses bcrypt)
- The other is a RUBY ON RAILS-app which uses `devise` (which also uses bcrypt) for authentication.
- On both apps I can register and login, separately.

When I transfer (copy/paste) the encrypted_password from Meteor's "bcrypt" field to Ruby's "encrypted_password" and try to login I get rejected. It does not work vice versa. Then I recreated the kind of salting by the meteor app in my ruby app (SHA-256 plain-password-hashing before they got compared against).

(here is the meteor accounts-password source file (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/oplog-backlog-on-1.0.3.1/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js ))

and this is my Ruby implementation:

```
class BCryptSHA256Hasher < Hasher
  def initialize
    @algorithm = :bcrypt_sha256
    @cost = 10
    @digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
  end

  def salt
    BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt(@cost)
  end

  def get_password_string(password)
    @digest.digest(password) unless @digest.nil?
  end

  def encode(password, salt)
    password = get_password_string(password)
    hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
    return hash
  end

  def verify(password, encoded)
    password_digest = get_password_string(password)
    hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password_digest, encoded)
    # password = "asdfasdf"
    # encoded  = "$2a$10$FqvtI7zNgmdWJJG1n9JwZewVYrzEn38JIxEGwmMviMsZsrCmYHqWm"
    # hash     = "$2a$10$FqvtI7zNgmdWJJG1n9JwZe22XU1hRDSNtHIrnYve9FbmjjqJCLhZi"
    # constant_time_comparison:
    constant_time_compare(encoded, hash)
  end

  def constant_time_compare(a, b)
    check = a.bytesize ^ b.bytesize
    a.bytes.zip(b.bytes) { |x, y| check |= x ^ y }
    check == 0
  end

end
```

Here is a valid `User`-document, which will be used by both servers:

```
{
  "_id": "g4BPfpavJGGTNgJcE",
  "authentication_token": "iZqmCsYS1Y9Xxh6t22-X",
  "confirmed_at": new Date(1457963598783),
  "createdAt": new Date(1457963456581),
  "current_sign_in_at": new Date(1457966356123),
  "current_sign_in_ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "email": "demo@demo.com",
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "demo@demo.com",
      "verified": true
    }
  ],
  "encrypted_password": "$2a$10$7/PJw51HgXfzYJWpaBHGj.QoRCTl0E29X0ZYTZPQhLRo69DGi8Xou",
  "failed_attempts": 0,
  "last_sign_in_at": new Date(1457966356123),
  "last_sign_in_ip": "127.0.0.1",
  "profile": {
    "_id": ObjectId("56e6c1e7a54d7595e099da27"),
    "firstName": "asdf",
    "lastName": "asdf"
  },
  "reset_password_sent_at": null,
  "reset_password_token": null,
  "services": {
    "_id": ObjectId("56e6c1e7a54d7595e099da28"),
    "password": {
      "bcrypt": "$2a$10$7/PJw51HgXfzYJWpaBHGj.QoRCTl0E29X0ZYTZPQhLRo69DGi8Xou"
    },
    "resume": {
      "loginTokens": [

      ]
    }
  },
  "sign_in_count": 1,
  "updated_at": new Date(1457966356127),
  "username": "mediatainment"
}
```

Comment: not sure, but maybe you could send a background HTTP request from Rails to meteor (or vice versa) to have concurrent updates? Or maybe configure Rails to use the Mongo DB (though you'd still have to solve the decryption problem).

Comment: It seems that the plain password runs through sha256 digest before  bcrypting it: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js

Comment: I already use mongoDb with rails

Comment: @Jan Can you give me a plain text password and its Meteor hash?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mediatainment/b451b021fbb34e61f3f6

Comment: Here is the gem I made for this case: https://github.com/mediatainment/devise_meteor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @maxpleaner's comment is the best way to handle authentication. But if really need to authenticate users separately, then just monkey patch devise.

**config/initializers/devise_meteor_adapter.rb**

```
module DeviseMeteorAdapter
  def digest(klass, password)
    klass.pepper = nil
    password = ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(password)
    super
  end

  def compare(klass, hashed_password, password)
    klass.pepper = nil
    password = ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(password)
    super
  end
end

Devise::Encryptor.singleton_class.prepend(DeviseMeteorAdapter)
```

WARNING: Not tested.

Comment: I want a plain password, and its meteor hash, so that I can test my solution.

Comment: password created with meteor `asdfasdf` result in db: `"services": {"password": {"bcrypt": "$2a$10$JadmqjFjF//B56ZTGRqkq.y9UMl55Z2SaJ0m.WYnLhlZBXgxEQngu" }`

Comment: Not fully tested because I know nothing about meteor, but It should work.

Comment: Not written tests right now, but it seems to be working! :-) Thank you!

Comment: @Aetherus Can you help me a little bit on how to call this? I am new to Ruby. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kishor If you want to manually call the methods, you can call them like `Devise::Encryptor.digest(User, 'P@ssword')` and `Devise::Encryptor.compare(User, '$2a$10$....', 'P@ssword')`